# When jquery.delegate call the event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Recently , Ive been using .delegate and .live a lot.They have a subtle difference when it comes to event capturing I guess.
When using live for link clicks like $('a').live("click",... , the links which had an image as their html content, ended up with the click handler getting the target as the image instead of the link.
Whereas with delegation ,it seems that it the link which is passed as the target.

What is the catch here?

Also, when exactly is a click handler called for .delegate, while the capturing phase or the bubbling phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between `.live` and `.delegate` is, that `.delegate()` uses a `context`. In other words, `.delegate()` is actually a wrapper for `.live()`, but instead watching the document root for bubbling events, it'll just watch a given root node.

For instance

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
});
```

will create an event handler attached to your `document.body`. This will catch absolutly all `anchors`-clicks that occur on your site.

```
$('#someDiv').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
});
```

will only "watch" all anchors which are childnodes from `#someDiv`.

It's unlikely that a delegated event by `.live()` have another target. Both `.live()` and `.delegate()` pass in the event object into the handler. It should make no difference at all, the `event.target` should always be the node of invocation.

Ref.: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)